# Zabbix Server Frontend 80 -> 443

Tags: https, zabbix, domain-name

I've a Zabbix installation on my CentOS 7 server and the following happens:

- Installed Zabbix Server with Frontend according to Official Install Guide (https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.0&os_distribution=centos&os_version=7&db=mysql&ws=nginx)
- Copied the server.conf information directly into `/etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/nginx/nginx.conf`
- Acquired an SSL cert for a domain name, I wish to use
- Modified the NginX config to accept only 443 with the same settings

Result:

- In Google Chrome, I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error

Workaround:

- If I enable the HTTP on port 80, via IP address I can access the frontend.

Desire:

- I want to make my Zabbix Frontend available via the domain name on HTTPS and not via IP on HTTP

The following setup works via IP and HTTP but with

- IP + HTTP
- Domain + HTTP
- Domain + HTTP

**nginx.conf**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/run/nginx/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/share/doc/README.dynamic.
include /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include       /etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    #include /etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     zabbix.mycompany.com;

        root    /usr/share/zabbix;

        index   index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found   off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /assets {
                access_log      off;
                expires         10d;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny            all;
        }

        location ~ /(api\/|conf[^\.]|include|locale) {
                deny            all;
                return          404;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/opt/rh/rh-php72/run/php-fpm/zabbix.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;

                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/share/zabbix;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
                fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
        }
}

server {
        listen          443 ssl;
        server_name     zabbix.mycompany.com;

        root    /usr/share/zabbix;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/zabbix.mycompany.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/zabbix.mycompany.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols   TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

        add_header      Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

        ssl_dhparam /etc/dhparam.pem;

        index   index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found   off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /assets {
                access_log      off;
                expires         10d;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny            all;
        }

        location ~ /(api\/|conf[^\.]|include|locale) {
                deny            all;
                return          404;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/opt/rh/rh-php72/run/php-fpm/zabbix.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;

                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/share/zabbix;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
                fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
        }
}

#    server {
#        listen       80 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /opt/rh/rh-nginx116/root/usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include      /etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx116/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#        location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
#        location = /50x.html {
#        }
#
#        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#        #
#        #location ~ \.php$ {
#        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#        #}
#
#        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#        #
#        #location ~ \.php$ {
#        #    root           html;
#        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#        #    include        fastcgi_params;
#        #}
#
#        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
#        # concurs with nginx's one
#        #
#        #location ~ /\.ht {
#        #    deny  all;
#        #}
#    }
#

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Also, here is a part of my `netstat -lntup` command result

```
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8267/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8267/nginx: master  
...
```

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: No error. :/ The browser is giving the error message, not NginX.

Comment: Are you actually connecting to the server, then?

Comment: Yes. I can access the server via SSH, HTTP and the agents from other servers can connect as well. The issue is, I cannot attach the domain name (even tho it has been set to the servers public IP address) in NginX. I've been working with NginX for 5 years now and never encountered anything like this. :/

Comment: Check for typos, then.

Comment: Checked. A million times. No typo.